# Is there a sequential version of GridUuid in GridGain?

Tags: java, uuid, gridgain

As the question says, is this possible in GridGain, that is sequential across all nodes in the grid?

This would be like the File Time based GUID generation provided by the [JUG](http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JugHome) Java library for sequential UUIDs, which is safe to use across Java VMs.

I have thought about using an `AtomicSequence` to try to roll my own version, but am worried about the overhead of having a non-cached sequence, and would prefer something out of the box, if possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [GridCacheAtlomicLong](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Distributed+AtomicLong) or  [GridCacheAtomicSequence](http://doc.gridgain.org/latest/Distributed+AtomicSequence) are the best options for this task.

Comment: Thanks Dmitriy. If I used GridCacheAtomicSequence, but I didn't want to cache any of the sequence numbers, would this be really bad? I'm worried that as the default for `atomicSequenceReserveSize` is 1000, and I would be setting it to 1, my performance would suffer too much

Comment: I am not sure I understand the concern. `GridCacheAtomicSequence` only keeps 1 long value in cache (it does not need to store all the values in the range). Setting `atomicSequenceReserveSize` to 1 makes `GridCacheAtomicSequence` work the same way as `GridCacheAtomicLong`, which means that every `incrementAndGet()` call will result in a distributed cache operation.

Comment: It's this sentence from the docs: "The key parameter of GridCacheAtomicSequence is atomicSequenceReserveSize which is the number of sequence values reserved . After a certain number has been reserved, consequent increments of sequence will happen locally without communication with other nodes until the next reservation has to be made", made me think this would be a terrible. I failed to realise that AtomicLong was actually doing the same thing, so performance should still be acceptable, but just not as good. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Reserving a range basically means if the sequence value is 100 and the range to reserve is of size 1000, then `GridCacheAtomicSequence` would set the global value of the sequence to 100 + 1000 = 1100, and then perform all further increments locally, e.g., 100 + 1, 100 + 2, etc... This is done for performance reasons, so every increment does not need to go over the network.